# Use the pumping lemma to prove that the following language is not context free

Tags: context-free, pumping-lemma

Can anyone help with the following problem ?

Let $B = \{ a^{n}b^{m}c^{m}d^{2n} | n,m ≥ 0 \}$, use the pumping lemma to prove B is not context-free

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, but $B$ _is_ context-free.

Comment: Sorry, you are right, there is probably a mistake in the description of the exercise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the following Context Free Grammar $G$:

$S \rightarrow aSdd\  |\ X\ |\ \epsilon$
$X \rightarrow bXc\ |\ \epsilon$

The language $L(G)$ generated by $G$ corresponds to the set of all the strings $\{\epsilon, add, aadddd, ..., bc, bbcc,..., abcdd, abbccdd,...\}$.
More generally, it corresponds to $ \{ a^{n}b^{m}c^{m}d^{2n} | n,m ≥ 0 \}$.

Comment: Sorry, you are right, there is probably a mistake in the description of the exercise. The language is context-free